# C readline function

Tags: c, strings, io

I wrote this function for my next learning project (cfg parser). What do you think about it?

```
char readline(FILE *fp, char **line, size_t *size) {
    *size = 0;
    size_t cpos = ftell(fp);

    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF) (*size)++;
    if (*size == 0 && c == EOF) {
        *line = NULL;
        return 1;
    }

    *line = calloc(*size + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (*line == NULL)
        return -1;

    fseek(fp, cpos, SEEK_SET);
    if (fread(*line, 1, *size, fp) != *size)
        return -2;

    fgetc(fp); // Skip that newline

    return 0;
}
```

Can be used as follows:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
char *line = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
readline(fp, &line, &size);
```

Answer (score 6):

- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.

  If you think that in future you might want to use another representation of characters (say, `wchar_t`), you'd have to modify code in more than one place. It is much safer to infer size from the variable, rather than from type:

  ```
  *line = calloc(..., sizeof(**line));
  ```

  This way there is a single modification point.

  Similarly, you may want to use `sizeof(**line)` instead of literal 1 in `fread`.
- `fseek` (and `ftell`)may fail with `EBADF` if the stream is not seekable. Since your function has no control over what kind of stream it is handled, it is advisable to test their return codes.
- One could argue that reading 0 characters is in fact a success (a client can tell the difference by examining `size`), so differentiating return codes (0 and 1) is redundant.

  It is highly recommended to use named macros (instead of magic numbers -1 and -2) for failure codes.

Comment: For what it's worth, I myself like using `sizeof(char)` despite it always being `1` --- it clarifies intent to the reader *and* makes the requirement to change more obvious if it ever gets changed to a different type (say, `wchar_t`). This is especially relevant in `malloc`, where you have a single argument:  `malloc(len)` becomes `malloc(len * sizeof(wchar_t))`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Profiling will tell, yet I doubt reading a file twice is faster than reading a file sequentially once and performing `realloc()` as needed.
2. `ftell(fp)` returns `long`.  Code should be `long cpos`.  `long` is a signed integer whose positive value *might* not fit in a `size_t`.  But more importantly, `long` may be insufficient for a file's size.  Consider `int fgetpos(FILE * restrict stream, fpos_t * restrict pos);` and `fsetpos()` instead.
3. It is important to check the returns of `ftell()`, `fseek()` for errors.
4. Rather than `calloc(*size + 1, sizeof(char));`, consider `calloc(*size + 1, 1)` or `calloc(*size + 1, sizeof *(*line))`.
5. As the intention is to return a pointer to a string, `*line` needs termination.  `calloc()` negates the need for `(*line)[*size] = '\0'`, but that is subtle and likely deserves a comment that the string is properly terminated.   I could see an update replacing `calloc()` with `malloc()` and not then explicitly terminating the string.
6. Curious that code does not save the `'\n'`.  With this code running in binary mode on various machines that use an alternate line ending like `"\r"`, maybe the *entire* file would then be 1 line as the is no `'\n'`.  Or in Windows with `"\r\n"`, each line ends with `'\r'`.  Recommend amending this code to work with more line ending than `'\n'` or insure only text mode is used.

[edit]

7. Nice use of `fseek(fp, cpos, SEEK_SET)` to go back to a position derived from `ftell()`.  This is better than `fseek(fp, cpos - *size, SEEK_SET);` which is UB for text files.
8. The return type `char` is weak.  `char` may be unsigned and returning `-1` could become `255`.  Suggest `int`.
9. About the sample usage: This `readline()` allocates memory, and should demo proper usage including `free()`:

   ```
   FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t size = 0;
   while (0 == readline(fp, &line, &size)) {
     puts(line);
     free(line);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be unknowingly [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel).  This function is similar to the [`getline()`](//stackoverflow.com/a/5597597/1157100) function specified in POSIX 1003.1-2008 — yet incompatible.  The order of the parameters is different, and your return value is less informative.  If you are implementing this function for your own amusement, or because your system lacks POSIX 2008 support, then you should mimic the `getline()` interface.

It is misleading to use `char` as the return type for a status code that is conceptually a number.  (`getline()` returns a `ssize_t` to indicate the length of the resulting string, or -1 for failure, with additional information in `errno`.)

Reading one character at a time with `fgetc()` is bad for performance.  I recommend using `fgets()` instead.  Then, your function would just act as a convenient memory reallocation wrapper for `fgets()`.  You would also avoid the need to seek, which lets your function work with unseekable streams.  It may take several tries to arrive at an overestimate of the required buffer size, but I think that it would still be better than reading the input twice.

Comment: I think the OP may be reinventing the whole car :-)  When doing a scanner/parser, it's generally simpler and much more efficient to use flex/bison to do the work.

Comment: Yet the implementations of `getline()` I find available on github et cetera all read the file one character at a time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. Return `int` instead of `char`, it is easily extensible for future and you may be able to match with standard POSIX `errno`. Else have explicit enum values to indicate return status.
2. Seems you are reading contents twice, once to determine size and then to actually read the entire line. Even though these are buffered fetches, measure and consider optimizing (also see 3.)
3. Mimic `scanf`. Read strings assuming caller has allocated enough memory for the line. That way you only need to do "append" as you read characters. In general, a bad idea to have memory allocation and de-allocation in separate functions. It is easy to miss a `free` and cause memory leaks. API should be designed so as to minimize user errors.
4. `fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]",buffer);` is usually a good substitute to read a single line

Comment: `Read strings assuming caller has allocated enough memory for the line.` `scanf`'s `%s` option is widely seen as broken unless it's being used for input that's known to be trusted and well formed (or a length limit is specified in the format). A general function (and really a non-broken) cannot make assumptions about buffer sizes. You're right that it's  uncomfortable to call `free()` on something you didn't get back directly from `malloc()`, but this is essentially a function made for handling the reallocation for you (in the same way some people wrap `fgets` to truly read a line).

Comment: (Continued) If it were a more complex thing being allocated than a c-string, I'd be all for creating a higher level data type, but at the end of the day, the usage of this function  seems completely reasonable (I would have it return a pointer instead of an error code, and I would have the error code be an optional out param, but different strokes), and doing anything else either cripples the functionality or introduces unnecessary complexity. This is one of the rare exceptions where `free()`ing some other function's doing seems sane.